# SignalR, WebAPI, Winforms or alternative

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, signalr

I have a simple Web API that receives POST messages from geographically dispersed clients.

I have a swathe of WinForms Applications that act as "satellite" applications which  send payloads to websites. So these applications maintain state, logins, and other functionality specific to each website they represent.

Theory is:

WebAPI receives a request, and sends it to the specific WinForms application which then forwards on the payloads as per its requirement.

So External Client->Web Api Post->?IPC MECHANISM HERE? Sends Payload->WinForms Delivers Payload->Sends Response back->Back up the pipe and back through WebAPI

Where I am "missing" at the moment is the most efficient and quickest way possible for my my POST Request, to get the message to the respective WinForms Application AND get a response.

I have been reading about signalR. I have been able to create a Hub and send a message to one client (which is all I have for testing now anyway). BUT - I have read this morning that I cannot get "return" messages back from my client.

Some of the SO messages about this are dated and brings me to my question - is  there any way I can achieve this with SignalR.

As an appendix to the question:
If not, are there alternative bits of tech I can be advised to review or pursue as an alternate?

FYI - I did have this all wired in internally to WebAPI itself which then simply responded with the return values, but as requirements have grown - "state"/"logins"/"sessions"/"cookies" need to be maintained which prompted the decision to "externalise" each payload delivery system.

Comment: There are [several tutorials on the Internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=signalr+sample+chat+application) that demonstrate two-way SignalR communication.

Comment: Sounds like a decent use case for Azure Functions (as a replacement for your WinForms apps)  You could trigger the functions via Http or Event Hubs.  if you stick with WinForms you could look into gRPC (protobuf).  But really you ought to stick with the simplest most maintainable solution and only add complexity as the need arrises - so TCP streams or UDP broadcast would be my tool of choice to begin with.

Comment: @SamAxe: So ... Just open a socket?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: That'd be where I'd start.  Serialize my request parameters as json.  Where would you start?

Comment: No, that sounds reasonable.

Comment: Not necessarily. The form is reusable and I have dependency injection doing all the magic for me, including reading configs that pertain to each site.

Comment: What else do the WinForms application do, eg is Winforms part of the problem or solution?

Comment: @Ian Ringrose - Right now - not much. I just built it out as a "test harness" type mechanism. So it could have easily been a console app (or anything else for that mater). So probably in the "problem" category rather than solution at this stage if looking objectively. I'm all for ideas.